# Unresolved imports from allauth

Tags: python, python-import, django-allauth

I am trying to use some imports from `allauth` but I get `Python(unresolved-import)`.

I have also pip installed django-allauth, and I am using a virtualenv.

This is my pip freeze from inside the virtual environment:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
asgiref==3.2.7     
autopep8==1.5.2    
certifi==2020.4.5.1
cffi==1.14.0       
chardet==3.0.4
coverage==5.1
cryptography==2.9.2
defusedxml==0.6.0
distlib==0.3.0
Django==3.0.6
django-allauth==0.42.0
django-cors-headers==3.3.0
django-rest-auth==0.9.5
django-rest-knox==4.1.0
djangorestframework==3.11.0
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
env==0.1.0
filelock==3.0.12
idna==2.9
oauthlib==3.1.0
pipenv==2018.11.26
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pycparser==2.20
PyJWT==1.7.1
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.23.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
urllib3==1.25.9
virtualenv==20.0.20
virtualenv-clone==0.5.4
```

Also, if I try to reinstall, the following message is returned:

```
Requirement already satisfied: django-allauth in c:\users\oricc\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (0.42.0)
```

I am just a beginner but as far as I can tell django cannot see allauth from my virtual environment because it is installed in the main python path.

What would be a good solution? Is it possible to install allauth inside the virtual environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and you *should* install it within the virtualenv. (Unless your virtualenv is created with `--system-site-packages`, it won't use those system-wide packages.)

You should clean up your global environment:

- Outside your virtualenv, run `pip list`. Look at packages that shouldn't be there (there could be a handful that are handy to have around globally, but generally as few as possible global packages, the better).
- Run `pip uninstall some-package-here` on those packages.

Then reinstall your requirements within your virtualenv (it could be a good idea to delete the virtualenv and create a new one in its place).

It's also generally a good idea to have the [`PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV` setting configured](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/pip-virtualenv/#requiring-an-active-virtual-environment-for-pip) so you don't accidentally install packages globally.

Comment: Thanks, very useful :) I have just uninstalled the package, deleted env and reinstalled it. I will further investigate PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV thou, because I didn't really get if I have to create a bashrc file somewhere or type that code alongside my pip install statement.

Comment: On Windows, you can set it in your system environment variable settings (System control panel).